# Change board permission with Trello with Trello.NET

Tags: c#, api, trello, trello.net

I'm using [Trello.net](https://github.com/detroitpro/Trello.net) to manage Trello boards through their API.

One thing I need to do, is change a new board I created to be public.

This code doesn't seem to work

```
myBoard.Prefs.PermissionLevel = PermissionLevel.Public;
trello.Boards.Update(myBoard);
```

Comment: It's not implemented. I might have time to fix it today. Follow progress here: https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/issues/7

Answer (score 2):

As of release 0.5.5-beta Trello.NET supports this. Use  `Trello.Boards.ChangePermissionLevel`. More info [here](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/issues/7).